# How can I get/construct a component like in a given example in swift/ios app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app and want to include a tutorial, basically couple slides next to each other, exactly like in this screenshot:

[image]

as you can see there are dots at the bottom and it's possible to slide right/left to see the content or click a text below to come back to sign in page.

I have already a view prepared for it in my storyboard:

[image]

and it is a UIViewComponent

```
class Tutorial: UIViewController {
```

I already added button at the bottom and linked it with another screen, but what about the dotted component with slides in it?

Comment: You should have a look at UIPageViewController. It's made to present pages of content and can show a page indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dots" are a UIPageControl.

The overall interface might be a UIPageViewController, which optionally comes with a UIPageControl.